# Checking database for changes to a field over time period

Tags: php, database, statistics, stat

not sure if this is possible to do but...

i have a follow function on my cms and would like a form of 'trending' posts that would allow me to show the posts that have gained the most followers over the past 7 days or so.

If i have a way of counting the amount of followers for today, is there a way i can check it against a past amount?

Or whats the best way around this? should i possibly be creating a script that will run a query on all the blogs, count there followers and store that in a DB field? I would make this happen every 7 days and run a check against this number and then the current follower amount?

Is this possibly over complicating things?

Thanks, Craig.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are headed towards a `Cron Job` that will run periodically

> If i have a way of counting the amount of followers for today, is there a way i can check it against a past amount?

Yes, save your data in a table just for this purpose. Then setup a script that checks this special table in your database where the stats are kept, and chooses the top ones. This table get's updated everyday, say at 00:00. With the data saved, you may query it to find out as much as you're saving in it

TLDR: this is kind of a project in itself, but I'm no expert